# Be through something

Tags: word-usage

A's mother asks him to get small potatoes from the attic, so his brother B asks him if A had looked through the containers carefully.  A says:

> I have been **through** them all.

Is the use of "through" natural?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. To "go through" something, or (generally referring to events in the pasts) "be through" something is used to refer to completing some sort of task on a set of things. It is most generally applicable to the idea of searching or similar, but it can also be used for other sorts of task.

> I packaged 500 food parcels, it took hours to **get through them all**.

The *to be* version is mostly used for things that represent an experience or sense perception, including searching or looking, but can include other things, too.

> I've **been through** dozens of lawsuits, and they don't get any easier.

That could mean someone had read through the records of the lawsuits, but stands here as an example of use where someone had experienced something more broadly. It might be said by someone who's been sued dozens of times, for instance.

Comment: For your final example at least, there are two different interpretations - *I've **examined** dozens of lawsuits*, OR *I've been [**put**] through* (been subjected to) *dozens of lawsuits*.

Comment: I'll clarify that; of course, I meant the latter, though I'd have used the word *experienced* rather than *been subjected to*.

Comment: Actually, that makes *three* possible senses, if we accept that *to have experienced* and *to have been subjected to* *(**put** through)* are potentially distinct meanings. Which latter would often, but not always, include the word ***put***.

Comment: I would say that *subjected to* is still a sense of experiencing, it just implies imposition and unpleasantness. Which is appropriate, in this case, but it wouldn't always be what someone wanted to emphasise.

Comment: *I went through several careers before settling on accountancy.* I guess that's essentially "experiencing", but it strongly implies *by my own choice*. Whereas *I was **put** through several careers before settling on accountancy* kinda implies someone else (perhaps "pushy parents") ***forced*** me to undergo those earlier experiences that didn't work out well.

Comment: Yes, adding the *put* changes it to having it imposed on your.

Comment: That was essentially my point, yes. But although it's true that actually including ***put*** removes all possibility of ambiguity in that respect, the exact same sense *could* sometimes be expressed *without* including it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any collection of things, often in something, and you **go through them**, it means you **examine them to see if they contain those things or something you are looking for.

For example:

**I went through my closet (clothes) to see what I no longer needed.**

**He went through his dirty laundry to find his favorite shirt.**

**We went through all our books and removed all paperbacks.**

Answer (score -1):

The of use 'through' sounds natural to my ear, but the 'them all' doesn't sound natural. I'd say "I've been through all of them." I don't think there is a grammar rule that promotes one over the other. I think it is a matter of style.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.